# Getting a range from the same sheet using the starting cell address and ending cell address

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am pretty new to Excel VBA and I have to create a macro for working on a large amount of data. the data is in the following sample format :

[image]

I am writing a function to get the range such that for each cell in column A, such as AAAA, I need to get the range B2:B4. I wrote a function that scans column A till it finds a non empty cell (startCell), then taking reference from that cell, it obtains the first cell B2 by doing :

```
Worksheets(sheetName).Cells(startCell.Row + 1, 2)

countStart = startCell.Row + 1
```

Then it runs a loop that counts the no of cells in column B starting at B2 (using countStart as row no.) till it encounters an empty cell and stores the count in say countFinal. I then want to obtain the range between

```
Worksheets(sheetName).Cells(startCell.Row + 1, 2)
```

and

```
Worksheets(sheetName).Cells(countFinal, 2)
```

The same needs to be done for the cells with BBBB and CCCC

How can I do this?

PS : I cannot share the code here since the code is on my office machine and I am posting from my home machine. But I can see if I can post it later if needed.

Comment: In such cases, you can use `xlDown` to get your range.

Comment: But how far down does xlDown go? I only need the range till just before the first blank cell encountered. For example, for AAAA, I need the range containing 1111,2222 and 3333 only. For BBBB : 5555,3333,4444 and so on.

Comment: Check the answer by KazJaw

Comment: Thanks, just looked up that xlDown points to the next blank cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to combine starting and ending Range points using this syntax:

```
Range(StartingCell, EndingCell)
```

which in your situation could go as follows:

```
Worksheets(sheetName).Range( _
    Worksheets(sheetName).Cells(startCell.Row + 1, 2), _
    Worksheets(sheetName).Cells(startCell.Row + 1, 2).End(XlDown))
```

Comment: Thanks. I shall check and see if this works and get back to you.

Comment: It works fine for ranges with multiple cells, however, if I want to try the same for ranges with single cells, it is selecting the cell from the next part as well. For example : [!prob](http://i.imgur.com/kig2OIk.jpg). When I use this, the range is coming to be the bottom cell (after the gap) as well. I do not want this to happen and that the cell should only be singular. How do I go about this?